# Updating and draw new line Datatable

Tags: javascript, ajax, datatable

I have a Javascript function that allows me to update a row (contained in a datatable) It opens several popup/modals and then I can modify row and send new values to my backend. The problem is the row is not updated directly in Datatable and I need new value without refreshing the entire page. Here is my entire logic :

```
    function updateImprimante(imprimanteId, updatedData) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'PATCH', // Ou PATCH, selon votre configuration de route Rails
            url: '/imprimantes/' + imprimanteId, // URL pour la mise à jour (à adapter)
            dataType: 'json', // Set the expected response data type
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
                    'Accept': 'application/json' // Set the Accept header to indicate JSON response
                },
            data: { 
                imprimante: updatedData 
                },
            beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'));
            },
            success: function(response) 
            {
                console.log('Mise à jour réussie', response);
                console.log(response)
                if(response.updatedImprimante) {
                    updateRowInDataTable(response.updatedImprimante.id, response.updatedImprimante);
                } else {
                    console.error('Updated data is missing in response');
                }
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.error('Erreur lors de la mise à jour', error);
            }
        });
    }

    function updateRowInDataTable(imprimanteId, updatedData) {
        var idToUpdate = parseInt(imprimanteId);            
        var row = table.rows(function(idx, data, node) {
            return $(node).find('.edit-imprimante-btn').data('imprimante-id') == idToUpdate;
        });

        if (row.any()) {
            row.data([
                updatedData.modele_ref,
                ...
            ]).draw();
        }
    }
```

How can I fix that ?